# Updated User Permissions Don't Reflect In Replica in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, database-replication

I have a master-slave configuration of PostgreSQL servers and there are multiple schemas defined in the database. Now both of master and replication servers have a user `readonly` which initially had only access to the `public` schema.

I have another schema, let's say `alt_schema`; and I want to give `readonly` user access to all it's tables.

Henceforth, I run the following query in master server to provide access of the schema to the user.

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA alt_schema TO readonly;
```

The above command successfully provided access of the schema's tables to the user.

But, the permissions are not propagated to the replication server (I waited for about 30 mins expecting there maybe some lag). Since, the automated replication failed, I tried to run the above query manually in the replication server itself, but obviously it gave me the below error:

```
ERROR:  cannot execute GRANT in a read-only transaction
```

Is there way to achieve the above.

> Note: My Postgres Servers are hosted in Google Cloud SQL.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I have a similar problem with the permissions not being propagated the replica in Google Cloud SQL.